# Can I use ng serve command after using ng build command?

Tags: angular, angular-builder

I have to deploy my application in a cloud server. For that purpose I need to run ng build command. However, I haven't completed my development in local machine. To continue the development and run the application, I need to run ng serve. So my question here is do I able to continue my development after deploying my application in cloud environment?

Comment: Yes, you can use `ng serve` and `ng build` as much as you want.

Comment: @Ramesh could you please give me an example.

Comment: Refer to the [docs](https://angular.io/cli/build) to know more about what they do. Once you have deployed your app you can just serve it in local using `ng serve` as you might've previously done...what's stopping you from doing this?

Comment: After deployment how do I run the application in other environment?

Comment: After deployment, you can continue with your development at your local machine and you can many times deploy your app by changing the version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So my question here is do I able to continue my development after
>   deploying my application in cloud environment?

There would not issues in running `ng serve` after you have run `ng build`. `ng build` will just get you the deployment files in your dist folder.

You can continue running the app using ng serve as many times as you want.

Please read through https://angular.io/guide/deployment

Comment: Not quiet ... there is a difference between build and run on my computer. This may have its origin from JavaScript version support, see here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14455#issuecomment-493739768